# How to Change GridView Column Color Based on Column Header

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, colors, header

How to change GridView column color based on column header in asp.net (vb.net)?
For example, when column header have text starts with "GT_" is will be red for the whole column, whereas header with "CF_" will be green.

Comment: do you want to change cell backround color change fro particular column?

Comment: yes, cell background color from particular column based on its column name.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Post your `aspx` markup here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rowdatabound event like this:

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{    
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
     DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;    
     for (int i = 0; i < drv.DataView.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
     {
       if (drv.DataView.Table.Columns[i].ColumnName.StartsWith("GT_"))    
        {
          e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen;
          grdAdd.Columns[i].HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Khaki;    
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Output Here
[image: output]

Comment: How do i call RowDataBound? I found that it's not stepping into the function

Comment: when you bind data with gridview , RowDataBound event fire and it means whenever you add a new row in gridview this event fire. so you do not need to call it explicitly, it will be called implicitly.

Comment: i already have GridViewID.DataBound() in Page_Load, but it does not step into the RowDataBound function given. I wrote it in VB: Protected Sub GridViewID_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

Comment: Vb.net is working same way just syntax are different. Did you set datasource?

Comment: yes, i have set the data source before binding and the data is shown on the gridview

Comment: seems like i need to set rowdatabound on design page first. let me try.

Comment: got it . right click on gridview in form design view and open property box and double click on RowDataBound event in event list . it will register this event and put my code inside this event

Comment: thanks, it works. how about having colors for the column header as well?

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GT_Test" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Maroon" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#ffb8a6" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"> add HeaderStyle-BackColor this in design view, you can see in example how it is setting

Comment: If the question is tagged vb.net with no c# tag, please present you code in vb.net. Tags have a purpose.

Comment: But the table does not have fixed columns, sometimes it may have "GT_" columns and sometimes it might not

Comment: grdAdd.Columns[i].HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Khaki; add this line. edited answer

Comment: It shows error on that line when running: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: i debug code and it is working fine..check number column and data which you are providing. it seems data having less number of column than gridview, if it is case you should tweak your code

Comment: hmm.. the gridview is directly binned with the datatable, which means the columns on datatable is same with the gridview. cell colouring working though. here's my code: https://pastebin.com/NCBEncY2

Comment: not solved yet.. can you check my code is it same with yours?

Comment: seems there is mismatch in number of column in trace and girdview column, check at this point

Comment: it seems that the problem was due to AutoGenerateColumns = "true" for the gridview. I'm still looking if there's any solution with the property set to true since the columns are dynamically changed according to the datatable.